# Client script in Timer is not working

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I was just trying to learn some Asp.net Ajax stuff and calling javascript from my C# script.

I have a timer that triggers a method that calls a super simple javascript alert function.
It also updates the time every 10 seconds. Now it looks like my code should work. There  are no build errors, no exceptions just it doesn't work. The C# part that updates the time. The javascript does not make the alert.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script runat="server">
        protected void Page_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            }
        }
        protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            const string someScript = "alertMe";
            Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),someScript, "alert('I was called from Content page!')", true);
        }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"> </asp:ScriptManager>
     <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
         <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1"></asp:Label>
             <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="10000" OnTick ="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
         </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Any of this is awful, but the UpdatePanel will need to be aware of any triggers so try adding one for the Timer.

Comment: Hmm, well the C# part that updates the Label works correctly and does an async postback that changes the time in the label every 10 seconds. I don't have any issues with the UpdatePanel, my issue is why isn't the javascript working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use ScriptManager instead of ClientScript when you are putting the element that triggers the postback inside an UpdatePanel.

Change your code to:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(), someScript, @"alert('I was called from Content page!');", true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much that works.  One small quick question. If I have  a javascript library already included in my page (lets say jQuery), Can I use jquery commands in the script I am passing in?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, it also works with jQuery or any other Javascript library.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a ;

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),someScript, "alert('I was called from Content page!');", true);
```

Most browsers have an error console of some type that you can see these issues as they occur.